# Dialogflow obtaining wrong dates for prebuilt date entities

Tags: dialogflow-es

Is there a way to change how Dialogflow automatically calculates the date meant by a text identified as a pre-built entity like "sys.date" or "sys.date-period"?

Or, is there a way to create your own entity for dates, and specify how it determines the specific day?

Depending on the day of the week, texts like "on Friday" are actually interpreted as the closest Friday to come in the future, instead of the most recent Friday that has already passed.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `@sys.date` entity then you can set the value as `date.recent`. It will always try to convert the phrase into most recent date.
For example, if you say **on monday**, it will give you date of recent monday.

Note that the `date.recent` option is available only for `@sys.date` not for `@sys.date-time` or `@sys.date-period`.

**EDIT:**
You need to select `$date.recent` from the options available
[image: dat1]
As you can see in the example screenshot below, tuesday is converted to most recent tuesday rather than upcoming tuesday.

[image: date2]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hmm that's strange. I don't see ```date.recent``` as a possible value, only ```date``` and ```date.original```: [screenshot](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/sMAbOW8C9kg5MWpWwJo5NS36tmewvDHb8z05n-c8LSP95AUAnibIKE1QvjTrWK0kEya3FAUV4S33rQ=w1855-h984-rw)

Comment: @carlosmartell97 the screenshot in your comment cannot be accessed (403 error)

Comment: @carlosmartell97 i have added details and screenshot in answer to make it more clear

Comment: Sorry for the broken screenshot link. It can now be seen [here](https://i.imgur.com/2sgexrQ.png). I'm not sure why I only see ```date``` and ```date.original``` as value options... Not even ```date.partial``` shows up!

Comment: @carlosmartell97 thats odd.

Comment: @sid8491 is there any place in the Dialogflow documentation which mentions these additional values (`recent`, `partial`, `original`) on the @sys.date entity? I can't find it [here](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/system-entities)

Comment: @VolodymyrOsmuk i was not able to find the documentation at the moment. i will try to find it later, meaniwhile you can tell me issue you are having.

Comment: @sid8491 Thank you. My colleague asked a question describing the issue we've faced -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56853343/problem-using-recent-attribute-of-sys-date-parameter-in-dialogflow