# Problem using .recent attribute of sys.date parameter in Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have question regarding Intent configuration in Dialogflow.

I've found information on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54683810/dialogflow-obtaining-wrong-dates-for-prebuilt-date-entities) regarding **".recent" attribute** of sys.date parameter.

The idea is that using value from that attribute gives a date that happened in the past (i.e. "Monday" will be translated to last Monday, not next Monday).

I've encountered a problem when using it with required parameters.
**The result in date interpretation differs depending on the input**:

- has the user provided all required parameters at once
- user has been prompted to deliver missing ones.

Please find example below - notice different dates returned for the same input

***Intent configuration***

[image: intent configuration - parameters]

[image: intent configuration - result]

***Behavior***

[image]

**Questions**:

1. Do you know what may be the problem here? It seems like a bug for me
2. I've searched and I have not been able to find documentation on
   Dialogflow's or Google's sites regarding ".recent" - do you know
   where I can find it?